# Gradient border doesn't fill header and footer section

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients, background-repeat

I am having problems inserting a background image and making my header and footer sections have a gradient background. My background image has to repeat. Does the .gif picture have to be in the same folder as the css? This is the css for it.

```
body {
    background-image: url("folder1/pic.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
}
```

I am also working on a linear gradient that goes from white to orange to black. This gradient would then be the background for the header and footer sections. I am able to split and provide the header and footer section a linear gradient background but it does not extend all the way to the border of my header and footer. This is the html section for the header

```
<header>
    <div id="eg1">
        <img src="images/pumpkin.gif" alt= "pumpkin" height="78" width="85">
        <h1>The Halloween Store</h1>
        <h3>For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
    </div>
</header>
```

The css formatting the html I have as

```
/*gradient header*/
#eg1 {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  white 0%, #ffa500 75%, #000000 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/t2rpsxk9/1/) the gradient shows fine and the background image also shows.

**Be aware**: On some browsers the gradient may not appear because of the browser version or the syntax.

So I used all the prefixes for gradient to be as many brosers as possible are supported:

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,  white 0%, #ffa500 75%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  white 0%, #ffa500 75%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  white 0%, #ffa500 75%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  white 0%, #ffa500 75%, #000000 100%);
```

For more about browser support check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)